# Magnitude of the value of a line at a point which does not lie on it

Tags: linear-algebra

This may be trivial but I had never thought of it before. I know that the sign of the value represents on which side of a line a point lies but don't know what the magnitude of that value represents.

Consider the line $3x+2y+1=0$, at $(-1,-2)$ it evaluates to $-6$, what does $|-6|$ represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't mean anything else unless one introduces more information: One could just as well write the same line as
$$6x + 4y + 2 = 0,$$
but evaluating the l.h.s. at $(-1, -2)$ gives $-12$, which has absolute value $12 \neq 6$.

Comment: please elaborate on "more information", maybe some example where it means something?

Comment: By "more information" I just mean that one introduces additional data, or a restriction on the form of the equation. For example, any line $L$ that does not pass through the origin has a unique representation $ax + by + 1 = 0$. In that case, one can draw lines parallel to $L$ with common spacing equal to the distance $d$ between $L$ and $0$ (so, in particular, one such line goes through $0$. Then, for any $(x, y)$, the quantity $|ax + by|$ tells you the distance between the line through $(x, y)$ parallel to $L$ as a multiple of $d$.

Comment: So, in your example, the distance between the origin and the line through $(-1, -2)$ and parallel to the line $L$ with equation $3x + 2y + 1$ is $6$ times the distance between the origin and $L$ itself.

Comment: got it, thanks.